# OpenStack: Keystone and nova-network inactive after reboot

Tags: centos, openstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-neutron, rdo

After Installing RDO (OpenStack Packstack) on **CentOS 7.2 (7.2.1511)** I always end up with following:

**Once OpenStack is successfully installed I can use OpenStack as intended.** 
Even that openstack-status returns:

```
..
openstack-nova-network:                 inactive  (disabled on boot)
openstack-keystone:                     inactive  (disabled on boot)
mysqld:                                 inactive  (disabled on boot)
.. (and some more)
```

**After a reboot of the system I cannot access Keystone anymore** (since it's disabled on boot) but also if I try to start the service manually with:

`service openstack-nova-network restart`

or all services with

`openstack-service start`

end in a timeout. So basically - once I've reboot the VM where I installed OpenStack I cannot use OpenStack anymore..

I installed with following commands:

```
sudo -i
systemctl disable NetworkManager firewalld
systemctl enable network
vi /etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=permissive

sync;reboot

vi /etc/enviroment
LANG=en_US.utf-8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8

yum install -y centos-release-openstack-mitaka
yum update -y
yum install -y openstack-packstack
packstack --allinone
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the some issue with openstack mitaka on centos 7 and this solved the issue:

`systemctl restart httpd.service`

Comment: Restarting the Httpd will restart the keystone and horizon services, but I am not sure if it can start a disabled service. Do you remember if the keystone was enabled in your case before you restarted the httpd?

Answer (score 1):

Since those services are disabled, they will not start when rebooted. You first need to enable the service and then start it. Refer to [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units).

```
systemctl enable openstack-keystone.service
systemctl start openstack-keystone.service
```